SqL Script Insert not finding column
Here is my sql script:
-- Create an in memory database for the tools rental project.
-- This is expected to be replaced with an actual database
--
-- Create Schema for use
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS Tools_R_Us_Schema;
USE Tools_R_Us_Schema;

-- Create the tool type table for listing the tool types
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tool_Type (
    type varchar(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

-- Create the vendor brands table for listing the brands
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Vendors (
    brand varchar(30) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

-- Create the tools table for listing the tools
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tools (
    code varchar(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    type varchar(20) NOT NULL REFERENCES Tool_Type(type),
    brand varchar(30) NOT NULL REFERENCES Vendors(brand)
);

-- Create the charge table based on tool type
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tools_Charges (
    id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    type varchar(20) NOT NULL REFERENCES Tool_Type(type),
    daily_charge decimal(5,2),
    weekday_charge bit,
    weekend_charge bit,
    holiday_charge bit
);

-- Create the holiday day falls on table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Holiday_Days_Of_Week (
    day_of_the_week varchar(15) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

-- Create the allowed frequencies of holiday table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Holiday_Frequency (
    frequency varchar(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

-- Create the holidays table for checking if it is a holiday
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Holidays (
    name varchar(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    holiday_month int,
    holiday_day int,
    day_of_the_week varchar(15) REFERENCES Holiday_Days_Of_Week(day_of_the_week),
    frequency varchar(20) REFERENCES Holiday_Frequency(frequency)
);

-- Create the list of valid statuses for rental
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tool_Status (
    status varchar(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

-- Create Rental table for tracking when a tool is rented
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tool_Rentals (
    id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    code varchar(10) NOT NULL REFERENCES Tools(code),
    type varchar(20) NOT NULL REFERENCES Tool_Type(type),
    brand varchar(30) NOT NULL REFERENCES Vendors(brand),
    rental_days int NOT NULL,
    checkout_date date NOT NULL,
    due_date date,
    charge_days int NOT NULL,
    due decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
    daily_charge decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
    pre_discount_charge decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
    discount_percent decimal(3,3),
    discount_amount decimal(10,2),
    final_charge decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
    status varchar(10) NOT NULL REFERENCES Tool_Status(status)
);

-- Populate the tool types
INSERT INTO Tool_Type (type)
    VALUES ('ChainSaw'),
           ('JackHammer'),
           ('Ladder');

-- Populate the vendor brands table
INSERT INTO Vendors (brand)
    VALUES ('Stihl'),
           ('Werner'),
           ('DeWalt'),
           ('Ridgid');

-- Populate the Tools table
INSERT INTO Tools (code, type, brand)
    VALUES ('CHNS', 'ChainSaw', 'Stihl'),
           ('LADW', 'Ladder', 'Werner'),
           ('JAKD', 'JackHammer', 'DeWalt'),
           ('JAKR', 'JackHammer', 'Ridgid');

-- Populate the charge table
INSERT INTO Tools_Charges (type, daily_charge, weekday_charge, weekend_charge, holiday_charge)
    VALUES ('Ladder', 1.99, 1, 1, 0),
           ('ChainSaw', 1.49, 1, 0, 1),
           ('JackHammer', 2.99, 1, 0, 0);

-- Populate the days of the week a holiday can fall on
INSERT INTO Holiday_Days_Of_Week (day_of_the_week)
   VALUES ('Monday');

-- Populate the frequencies for holidays allowed
INSERT INTO Holiday_Frequency (frequency)
    VALUES ('First');

-- Populate the holidays table
INSERT INTO Holidays (name, holiday_month, holiday_day, day_of_the_week, frequency)
    VALUES ('Independence Day', 7, 4, null, null),
           ('Labor Day', null, null, 'Monday', 'First');

-- Populate the valid statuses for rentals
INSERT INTO Tool_Status (status)
    VALUES ('ACTIVE'),
           ('CLOSED');


Here is the error:
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "TYPE" not found; SQL statement:

Then the trace has:
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #14 of file [/Users/paqpaq/Dropbox/WORK/CF/pa1024/build/resources/main/data.sql]: INSERT INTO Tools (code, type, brand) VALUES ('CHNS', 'ChainSaw', 'Stihl'), ('LADW', 'Ladder', 'Werner'), ('JAKD', 'JackHammer', 'DeWalt'), ('JAKR', 'JackHammer', 'Ridgid')

I get an error on inserting into Tools or Tools_Charges that is can not find column "type".  I have tried changing the name and that does not fix the issue.  I have run this through a sql validator and it validates.  So I am at a loss at what is wrong.
On the off chance it makes a difference, this is in Intellij setup for an H2 Database.  And it was working and then stopped and the only thing I changed was on Tool_Type I added the underscore because it was oddly adding it in the H2 Console.
Thoughts?

please add alwaas the complete error message to your question

@nbk error added but it is not very descriptive.

and changimg all type to t_type ?

#nbk changing to t_type just changes the error to reflect 'Column "T_TYPE" not found; SQL statement:'

Please provide a minimal example demonstrating the problem and attach the full error log.

@nik0x1 this is everything. I have a minimal spring boot app with an h2 database. On startup it runs this script to create tables and populate with data. That fails with the two error lines about and halts startup. There is no additional items.

Reduce the number of tables and fields in them to the minimum where the error still occurs. Remove comments in the code listing (this is not essential information in this question, but it interferes with determining the line number of the code).

Your script runs fine for me with the latest H2 download

@g00se hmmmmm. I made sure I am using the latest and it still gives the same error. Wonder if this is a configuration issue.

Did you try the suggestion by @nik0x1?

Select and run each individual script in sequence. I am assuming you ran everything at once and your IDE is checking for tables and columns before creating the tables because the script looks fine.

It looks like the schema is messing it up.  If I leave it then there is an issue even though I am using it.  If I take it out it works.

It appears it has nothing to do with the sql. Instead when I changed the java polo to not use @OneToOne and instead just map the column it all worked. So it was something with that. Not sure how because the fields exactly match the tables but it is working now.

So it appears that the issue was not with the SQL.  Instead, it was with the Java POJO that I had created as an @Entity.  I was using @OneToOne for the foreign key reference and even though all the names were the same it was saying it could not find the column.  Changing the @OneToOne to just an @Column fixed the error.  The database still holds the key relationship.  Everything I read stated what I had should work but it did not.  At least I am able to move forward.
